# Record exist in zf2 with clause

Tags: php, database, zend-framework2, validation

My user table has following columns and data.

id | name | is_deleted

##########################

1  | dinu | 1

2  | dddd | 0

I want to check non deleted user is exist. How can i do it?

I use following code for check user with out is_deleted at edit user. Now I want to check user rows with is_deleted. I use exclude for check current user id.

```
$validator = new Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists(
    array(
        'table'   => 'users',
        'field'   => 'name',
        'exclude' => array(
             'field' => 'id',
             'value' => $id
        )
    )
);

if ($validator->isValid($username)) {

}
```

The standed validation document has following code. But i can't use it.

```
$email     = 'user@example.com';
$clause    = $db->quoteInto('email = ?', $email);
$validator = new Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists(
    array(
        'table'   => 'users',
        'field'   => 'username',
        'exclude' => $clause
    )
);
```

What is $db ? it is not adapter. I try it. Please help me again.

Answer (score 5):

I think that ZF2 Validation Classes manual's part about clauses is outdated.

`quoteInto()` method was removed in ZF2

However, I get quote-based Db validation filter to work..

You can use "where" expression as string, like this:

```
$clause = "id != $myid AND status != false";
```

..or use associative array as mentioned above.

And then:

```
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name'    => 'Db\NoRecordExists',
                'options' => array(
                    'adapter' => $dbAdapter,
                    'table' => $tableName,
                    'field' => $fieldName,
                    'exclude' => $clause,
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i do not know if this is true for ZF2, too, but for now i will just assume this is the case. In ZF1 we had the option to exclude a single field. Try the following:

```
$validator = new Zend\Validator\Db\RecordExists(array(
    'table' => 'users',
    'field' => 'name',
    'exclude' => array(
        'field' => 'is_deleted',
        'value' => 1
    )
));
```

This should tell the validator something like. `Look for user with name $name but is_deleted 0`

Comment: Thank sam for replay. I already use exclude for check user id at  edit user. Actually i want to know how use clause.

Comment: Same problem I am getting for check duplicate on multiple fields. If anybody know how to use Validator RecordExists to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a custom validator in Zendframework 2 [Include Records validator](https://gist.github.com/4635137).
Only include those records to validate which are not deleted.

I have created a Custom Validator oposite to Exclude, which is include.

```
<?php

//Check no other users have the username

$user_id = $user->getId();

$validator = new Zend\Validator\Db\CustomNoRecordExists(

array(

'table' => 'users',

'field' => 'username',

'include' => array(

'field' => 'id',

'value' => $user_id

)

)

);



if ($validator->isValid($username)) {

// username appears to be valid

} else {

// username is invalid; print the reason

$messages = $validator->getMessages();

foreach ($messages as $message) {

echo "$message\n";

}

}



?>
```